# Realm:- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am working on a Project(iOS) that is based on `Objective-C` and `Swift`, The  offline storage is used in the Application is `Realm` and `Realm-Cloud` to sync the data-objects between the client and the server.

When I got the project the RealmModels inside the project were missing and so I copied the the realmModels from the Android Project and created the missing models. After creating the models the project stated to build and running.

But Now the issues is, when the realm database is downloaded completely  But while accessing the data-objects from realm database the Application is crashing with the Exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value 'alpha-numeric-string' to initialize object of type 'modelName': missing key 'id''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1af008518 0x1ae1e39f8 0x1046a0e14 0x1046a02fc 0x10469acd0 0x102999cdc 0x1029993c8 0x102998db8 0x10293a50c 0x10293b508 0x1028fa5a0 0x1aef795bc 0x1aef79588 0x1aef78a7c 0x1aef78728 0x1aeef2524 0x1aef781d8 0x1af960814 0x1029acd90 0x102915320 0x105def6f0 0x105df0c74 0x105dfe6fc 0x1aef99ec0 0x1aef94df8 0x1aef94354 0x1b119479c 0x1db407b68 0x102902638 0x1aea5a8e0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am adding the necessary models and code where I debugged.

**RealmModel.h**

```c
@interface association : RLMObject
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(association)

@interface association()
@property NSString *id;
@property BOOL isDeleted;
@property (nullable) NSDate *createTime;
@property (nullable) a *createdBy;
@property (nullable) NSDate *updateTime;
@property (nullable) a *ab;
@property (nullable) b *ac;
@property (nullable) c *cd;
@end
```

**RealmModeals.m**

```c
@implementation association

+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)requiredProperties {
    return @[
        @"id",
    ];
}

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}

@end
```

**Realm.swift**

```swift
import Foundation

typealias Association = association
```

**Association.swift**

```swift
static func AssociationForCurrentDevice() -> Association {
        var association: Association! = Association(value: DeviceUUID.current.string) . ----> App is crashing in this line with the above mentioned error.

        return Association
    }
```

I tried to open the RealmDatabase (one with .realm extension). I am getting the error that I can open the file once I have to enter a valid encryption key to decrypt the file. ( where to find the key?)

(Attached Image). 
[image: Error While opening Realm Database.]

Thanks in Advance. If more information is required feel free to comment.